# Customizing Element Properties Menu in Enterprise Architect

Tags: enterprise-architect

I have created a new stereotype based on "Requirement" and has exported it as profile. When I double click on an instantiation of that type, a menu appears that contains the default properties of the type "Requirement". It contains some tabs (e.g. the "Files" tab) that are useless to me.

Is there a way to eliminate this tabs?
How can I modify the default tabs of the properties dialog (open by double click on an element)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A word of warning: be careful when stereotyping Requirements - the relationship between the element stereotype and the requirement types configured into the project (Settings - Project Types) is a bit murky.

That said, there is no way to modify EA's dialogs. What you can do is create your own property dialog and have EA open that when the user double-clicks the element.

In order to achieve this, you need to create an Add-In which catches the Context Item Event `EA_OnContextItemDoubleClicked`. In your event handler, return `true` to inform EA that you're handling the event (which prevents EA from opening the default property dialog), and open your own custom dialog.

The same event is fired when the user hits Enter with the element selected. The default property dialog can still be opened by pressing Alt-Enter.

As an alternative, you might want to look into the third-party extension [eaForms](http://www.eaworkplace.com/tools/eaforms), which allows you to create your own custom property dialogs without writing your own Add-In.

Comment: Your alternative solution to overwrite "double click" trigger is quite helpful. 
About the relationship between the element stereotype and the requirement types which is murky, would you explain a little?